Conditional rendering not working for flutter widgets
Inside the build method 
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final provider = Provider.of<StateProvider>(context, listen: false);

    // Get the selected question details from the StateProvider
    final selectedQuestion = provider.selectedQuestion;

    // Check if the question is disabled
    final bool isQuestionDisabled = selectedQuestion['isActive'];

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/left_arrow.svg'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
              context,
              Provider.of<StateProvider>(context, listen: false).selectedRoute,
              (route) => false, // Remove all routes in the stack
            );
          },
        ),
        actions: const [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            child: Text(
              '+3 Guidos online',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xFF00FF38),
                  fontSize: 10,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
            color: const Color(0xFF191919),
            child: questions(
              selectedQuestion['title'],
              selectedQuestion['description'],
              selectedQuestion['tags'][0],
              selectedQuestion['priority'],
              selectedQuestion['timeLeft'].toString(),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: _reloadChatMessages,
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/images/community.png',
                      height: 306,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 50),
                      child: Text(
                        'Help out your peer Exploro and earn rewards',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xFF818181),
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  ListView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                    reverse: true,
                    itemCount: _messages.length + 1,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      if (index == 0) {
                        return _isRefreshing
                            ? Container(
                                height: 80.0,
                                child: Center(
                                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                ),
                              )
                            : SizedBox.shrink();
                      } else {
                        final message = _messages[index - 1];
                        final firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
                        final userUid = firebaseUser?.uid ?? '';
                        final isUserMessage = message['user'] == userUid;

                        return isUserMessage
                            ? SendMesage(
                                proPic: message['profileImage'],
                                text: message['type'] == 'LOCATION'
                                    ? ''
                                    : message['message'],
                                time: _formatTimestamp(message['timestamp']),
                                type: message['type'],
                                isSentByUser: isUserMessage,
                                coordinates: message['type'] == 'LOCATION'
                                    ? message['message']
                                    : {},
                              )
                            : IncomingMessage(
                                text: message['type'] == 'LOCATION'
                                    ? ''
                                    : message['message'],
                                time: _formatTimestamp(message['timestamp']),
                                proPic: message['profileImage'],
                                type: message['type'],
                                iseSentByUser: isUserMessage,
                                coordinates: message['type'] == 'LOCATION'
                                    ? message['message']
                                    : {},
                                user: message['user'],
                              );
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          if (isQuestionDisabled)
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onTapOutside: (event) {
                        print('onTapOutside');
                        FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
                      },
                      controller: _messageController,
                      maxLength: 200, // Set max length
                      maxLengthEnforcement: MaxLengthEnforcement.enforced,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Message',
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: const Color(0xFF2A2A2A),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                        ),
                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 10,
                          horizontal: 20,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/up_arrow.svg'),
                    onPressed: _sendMessage,
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.attach_file),
                    onPressed: () {
                      showModalBottomSheet(
                          elevation: 0,
                          context: context,
                          builder: (builder) => AttachmentBottomSheet(
                              loadMessages: _loadChatMessages));
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: isQuestionDisabled
          ? BottomAppBar(
              child: Container(
                height: 56.0,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Session Ended',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          : Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  CustomTextButton(
                    text: 'Report',
                    onPressed: () {
                      showModalBottomSheet(
                          elevation: 0,
                          context: context,
                          builder: (build) => reportSheet());
                    },
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    borderColor: const Color(0xFF0C8CE9),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 10,
                    ),
                  ),
                  CustomTextButton(
                    text: 'Quit',
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
                    },
                    backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFFF5050),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
    );
  }

bottomNavigationBar works with the condition isQuestionDisabled but,
if (isQuestionDisabled)
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  onTapOutside: (event) {
                    print('onTapOutside');
                    FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
                  },
                  controller: _messageController,
                  maxLength: 200, // Set max length
                  maxLengthEnforcement: MaxLengthEnforcement.enforced,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Message',
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: const Color(0xFF2A2A2A),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                      borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                    ),
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 10,
                      horizontal: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/up_arrow.svg'),
                onPressed: _sendMessage,
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.attach_file),
                onPressed: () {
                  showModalBottomSheet(
                      elevation: 0,
                      context: context,
                      builder: (builder) => AttachmentBottomSheet(
                          loadMessages: _loadChatMessages));
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )

this always works opposite for the given value. Above row should disappear for

isQuestionDisabled == true

Confused why the rendering is working for

() ? value1 : value2

but not for

if ()

It seems like there's an issue with the conditional rendering inside the build method. This should correctly render the UI based on the value of isQuestionDisabled, however there might be another issue elsewhere in the code 

An if condition will only run the next code if the condition is true, in this case, if (isQuestionDisabled) will make the widget appear only if isQuestionDisabled == true, if you want it not to appear when the question is disabled you should replace isQuestionDisabled with !isQuestionDisabled
condition ? value1 : value2 works because you are using it correctly, it will show value1 if condition is true and value2 if it is false

Gotcha!  silly me
